# Recurrent events

Tags: android

How can I fetch recurring events from native android calendar?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "native android calendar", at least in terms of the Android SDK.

If you are referring to some app that displays the user's Google Calendar, use the [Google Calendar GData API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/) to access the calendar's events.